Is there more to Deadpool's "The B*b Queen of Saskatoon" retort to Wolverine than just crude humor?
In the film Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), there's a scene where the titular characters engage in an argument. Wolverine accuses Deadpool of being a liar, to which Deadpool retorts, "They call me The Merc with the Mouth, not Truthful Timmy, the Bl-wj-b Queen of Saskatoon."
I'm curious about the layers of humor in this line. Is the joke primarily based on its crude and potentially offensive nature? Or is there more to this quip? I get the humor up to "Truthful Timmy," but I'm a bit lost on what additional comedic value "the Bl-wj-b Queen of Saskatoon" brings to the table.
Saskatoon is a city in Canada, so I'm thinking that there might be a Canada-specific reference or joke that might not be immediately apparent to non-Canadian viewers. Is this perhaps alluding to something specific in Saskatoon?
I'm aware that both Ryan Reynolds, who portrays Deadpool, and Wolverine are Canadian, so this could be a nod to their shared heritage. However, I'm uncertain about the specific significance of "Saskatoon" and the "Bl-wj-b Queen" title in this context.
Interestingly, a Reddit post mentions that the film's credits include a special thanks to "Truthful Timmy, the Bl-wj-b Queen of Saskatoon."
Can anyone shed light on the intended humor or cultural references in this line?

I'm Canadian (east coaster though) and have absolutely no idea what that means. I suspect it's just an oddball throwaway. I'm interested in the answer as well!

The character of Logan (Wolverine) is also Canadian, although again I don't know what the relevance would be.

In the original Deadpool (2016) there was a line poking fun at the Saskatchewan city of Regina: "Oh! And that's why Regina rhymes with fun!"  I suspect it's just the Canadian habit of poking a bit of fun at the Prairie provinces (well, all of the provinces, really).

Utterly unrelated, but the town is also referenced in a Tom and Jerry cartoon "The Zoot Cat", where tom is referred to as "A goon from Saskatoon".

I would venture it's simply that Saskatoon is a funny-sounding place name, like Walla Walla, Keokuk, Cucamonga, or Seattle.

I've lived in Saskatoon (in the province of Saskatchewan), Canada for the last 7 years and got to hear the gasps and laughter at this comment from other local Saskatoon folks during the first showing of Deadpool & Wolverine on Thursday afternoon at the 8th Street Cineplex here in S'toon.
I'm not originally from here, but my wife has lived here since she was a kid. Although she's never heard of anyone called "Truthful Timmy," the only real assumption we could think of is the fact that Wade mentions in the first movie that he's from a town called Regina, SK. (Remember "Regina rhymes with... fun!")
Regina is about 2.5 hours from Saskatoon, and there's a bit of a long-standing rivalry between Regina and Saskatoon. One reason is that while Regina is the Provincial Capital of Saskatchewan, the University of Saskatchewan is found in Saskatoon.
So if I were going for a Marvel "No-Prize," it would be that Wade's from Regina and he's insulting Logan AND throwing shade at Saskatoon at the same time.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
